# Where is 'Close when download finished' in uTorrent?

Tags: macos, utorrent

On Windows I had a version of uTorrent that would close the software when the download finishes.

I'm on a Mac now, with the latest version, I don't see that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the Mac version, but I don't think it has the option. It does however have the option to run a program when the download finishes (properties of torrent, advanced tab), where you could have it run a script that shuts down utorrent, but that's the only thing I can think of to get what you want.